# Paginate array (not from DB) cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, pagination, cakephp-2.2

In controller I'm getting array of news from web-service  `$news = json_decode(@file_get_contents($submenu), true);` and I need to paginate this array to 6 news per page. My array's structure:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '716',
        'city_id' => null,
        'language' => 'lit',
        'header' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
        'description' => '<p>Sed  diam  nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.',
        'short_description_img' => '',
        'autor' => 'Avio',
        'friendly_link' => 'Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet_1346393036',
        'created' => '2012-08-31 09:03:56',
        'general_tag' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'agency_id' => null,
            'project_id' => null,
            'active' => null,
            'language' => null,
            'title' => null,
            'friendly_link' => null,
            'healthcare_trip_tag' => null,
            'created' => null
        ),
        'tags' => array()
    )
        (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '717',
        'city_id' => null,
        'language' => 'lit',
        'header' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
        'description' => '<p>Sed  diam  nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.',
        'short_description_img' => '',
        'autor' => 'Avio',
        'friendly_link' => 'Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet_1346393036',
        'created' => '2012-08-31 09:03:56',
        'general_tag' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'agency_id' => null,
            'project_id' => null,
            'active' => null,
            'language' => null,
            'title' => null,
            'friendly_link' => null,
            'healthcare_trip_tag' => null,
            'created' => null
        ),
        'tags' => array()
    )
         .................
)
```

Tried default pagination method as shown in CakePHP documentation but no luck. Thanks for advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `copy cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php` to `app/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php` , then override the paginate function in it.
By Simple changes you have array paginator.